# How to retrieve all the css properties of an element using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

`value_of_css_property(property_name)` returns value for a particular property.

But I want know if there is any way we can get all the css properties?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try below to get property names:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
properties = driver.execute_script('return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], null);', element)
```

or to get all values of properties

```
element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
properties = driver.execute_script('return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], null);', element)
for property in properties:
    print(element.value_of_css_property(property))
```

Answer (score 0):

`element.get_property('style')` will give you all the properties

example:

```
print(e.get_property('style'))
['height', 'width', 'visibility', 'position', 'z-index', 'font-family', 'font-size', 'font-weight', 'font-style']
```